# Flutter: how to stop an audio started from AndroidAlarmManager

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager

I have this flutter app:
[image: Main page]

I have a static class:

```
class AudioPlayerController {
  static AudioPlayer _audioCache = AudioPlayer();

  // static Future<void> initialize() async {
  //   await _audioCache.load('audio/song.mp3'); // Load the audio file
  // }

  static Future<void> play() async {
    await _audioCache.play(AssetSource('audio/song.mp3')); // Play the audio file
  }

  static Future<void> pause() async {
    await _audioCache.pause(); // Pause the audio playback
  }

  static Future<void> resume() async {
    await _audioCache.resume(); // Resume the audio playback
  }

  static Future<void> stop() async {
    await _audioCache.stop(); // Stop the audio playback
  }
}
```

The start/stop audio work fine from the main page, but when I am triggering the alarm, the audio cannot be stopped:

```
 ElevatedButton(
                key: const ValueKey('RegisterOneShotAlarm'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
                    const Duration(seconds: 15),
                    Random().nextInt(pow(2, 31) as int),
                    callback,
                    exact: true,
                    wakeup: true,
                  );
                  _setupNotification();
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Schedule OneShot Alarm',
                ),
              ),
```

```
  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> callback() async {
    developer.log('Alarm fired!');
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final currentCount = prefs.getInt(countKey) ?? 0;
    await prefs.setInt(countKey, currentCount + 1);
    uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
    uiSendPort?.send(null);
    AudioPlayerController.play();
  }
```

My question is: why is it not working if the player starts playing from the callback function? How can I make the player start playing from the callback when an alarm is triggered and be turned off from the button on the main Page?